# How to find unique column which has wrong entry with other column MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have table "rec" in MySQL  like

```
ID TPI   ROLE   percent
1  10   ADMIN    80
2  20   USER     20
3  10   USER     90
4  20   USER     60
```

All tpi can be either ADMIN or USER but by mistake, TPI 10 is set in both role . How can I found those TPI which have both role in the table . It is just dummy table in real table I have 1000s of data.

I am trying something like

```
   SELECT DISTINCT TPI,ROLE  FROM `rec` GROUP BY TPI HAVING(COUNT(TPI)) > 1
```

But I am not getting desire output

Comment: What output do you want to get?

Comment: In this case one record TPI 10 @MaximFedorov

Comment: Then just use :  SELECT TPI FROM `rec` GROUP BY TPI HAVING(COUNT(TPI)) > 1

Comment: @ChandanRajput `DISTINCT` in your query is superfluous.  `GROUP BY` should already remove all duplicates.

Comment: Correct @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @ChandanRajput no this gives me all uniqe TPI

Comment: "no this gives me all uniqe TPI" Topicstarter `GROUP BY TPI` also gives unique TPI like @TimBiegeleisen and @ChandanRajput are telling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to find those users having more than one role, then we can try aggregating:

```
SELECT TPI
FROM rec
GROUP BY TPI
HAVING MIN(ROLE) <> MAX(ROLE);
```

### Demo

The major problems with your current query is that you are selecting `ROLE` while aggregating only by `TPI`.  This does not make any sense.  Also, `HAVING` is not a function in SQL, it is an operator, so it doesn't take parentheses after it.

Comment: @Cid Yes, they do.  Have you checked my demo?

Comment: Now I did. the documentation on [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_min.asp) says *"A numeric value (can be a field or a formula)"* concerning the parameter, which differs from the official documentation on [dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min). They should update it

Comment: That's why you should not use W3School @Cid

Comment: @Cid I hate using W3School as a reference and only use it if it comes up first and I'm too lazy to search elsewhere.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it came first, and they improved their documentation concerning HTML and JS. Looks like it's still stupid for SQL

Comment: It seems very interesting answer :)

Comment: They call it  `W3School` with a reason @Cid where do you think the name is coming from? i think it is named after `World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)` the organisation which makes the recommendations about HTML, CSS and Javascript standards so it would make more sense that the HTML, CSS and Javascript documentation/tutorials on `W3School` are more correct.

Comment: I reported that error on their site giving them a friendly RTFM

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, and it leads to confusion giving them more credit, they aren't affiliated to W3C,

Answer (score 2):

You could check for distict ROLE

```
select tpi, count(distinct ROLE)
from  `rec` 
GROUP BY tpi  HAVING count(distinct ROLE)  > 1
```

or for ROLE

```
select tpi, count( ROLE)
from  `rec` 
GROUP BY tpi  HAVING count( ROLE)  > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same using below query.

```
SELECT TPI  FROM `rec` GROUP BY TPI HAVING(count(distinct ROLE)>1);
```